# Where is the "Mark Object" menu option in IntelliJ IDEA 11?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

According to http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/11/new-in-11-mark-object-action-in-javascript-debuggers/ we should have it right there in the context menu. Well, I cannot find it there:
[image]
[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark Object feature was dropped when changing debugger protocols. We plan to introduce it again soon, [follow this feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7763).